# Roblox Lua Map Generation Optimization

Tags: optimization, random, lua, roblox

I am trying to make a Roblox script that automatically generates a infinite path, but it gets really slow after a while. I want to know if it is possible to only generate a certain section of the map at a time. I want the player to be able to move around on the path without it changing, but I want to load in/out different parts of the map that are close to the player so it doesn't take up as much compute power.

This is what I have so far:

```
local seed = 1234567890
math.randomseed(seed)
local minX = -10
local maxX = 10
local posX = math.random(minX, maxX)
local posY
local posZ
local rowMax = 10
local colMax = 10
local row = math.random(3, rowMax)
local column = math.random(3, colMax)
local randomChoice = {-1, 1}
local posNeg
local x = 0
local numParts = 2000
local length = 1


while true do
    for i = 1, numParts do
        if x < column then
            local part = Instance.new("Part")
            part.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
            posY = 0
            posZ = -24.5 - length
            part.Position = Vector3.new(posX, posY, posZ)
            part.Anchored = true
            part.Parent = workspace
            x = x + 1
        else
            posNeg = randomChoice[math.random(#randomChoice)]
            for j = 1, row do
                local part = Instance.new("Part")
                part.Size = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
                posY = 0
                posZ = -24.5 - length
                part.Position = Vector3.new(posX, posY, posZ)
                part.Anchored = true
                part.Parent = workspace

                if (posX + posNeg >= -25) and (posX + posNeg <= 25) and (j < row) then 
                    posX = posX + posNeg
                end
            end
            x = 0
            row = math.random(3, rowMax)
            column = math.random(3, colMax)
        end
        length = length + 1
    end
    wait(2)
end
```

Comment: In order to reproducibly recreate a section of the map it needs a certain randomseed for each section.